# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: items on DropDownListFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to return a list of emails from a model using DropDownListFor. I have found a few topics on this issue, so it seems to be common, and I presume the list needs to be repopulated, but I can't find a way that works (or a way that I understand against the other examples).

I always get the null error regardless of what I do. I'm thinking that maybe actually it is not returning any emails in the first place, but I'm not understanding the way dropdownlist works with a model.

Is there a different issue causing the null that I can't see right now?

I define the list in a class:

```
public class User {
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> EmailList { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ChangeDetails()
{
    var u = new User();
    ViewBag.DropDownList = new SelectList(u.EmailList, "Email", "Email");
    return View(u);
}
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Email, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.DropDownList, "---Select a value---", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

Error message:

```
Message: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: items

at System.Web.Mvc.MultiSelectList..ctor(IEnumerable items, String dataValueField, String dataTextField, String dataGroupField, IEnumerable selectedValues, IEnumerable disabledValues, IEnumerable disabledGroups) ....
```

Comment: try passing "ViewBag.DropDownList" in the SelectList inside your razor view, rather than Model.EmailList

Comment: @Nirman I actually had that in and changed it to `new SelectList` ... trial and error really. Edited the main post to add the ViewBag in razor.

Comment: Because `u.EmailList` is `null` (you did not initialize it, let alone populate it with any items)

Comment: @Stephen Muecke How can I populate it with items? Been trying to wrap the answer (`lst`) below in a foreach and doing `SelectListItem item in user.EmailList`, but to no avail. I feel like I'm not understanding something.

Comment: But all you have done is `var u = new User();` which just initializes a new `User` which wont have any items. And you do not even need `ViewBag.DropDownList = ...` The model already contains a property `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> EmailList` so in the view its just `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Email, Model.EmailList, "---Select a value---", new { ... })` (except that you must first initialize `EmailList` so its not `null`)

Comment: But I have no idea where you want the values of existing emails to come from. Do you have a database of emails that you want the user to select from?

Comment: Yes. There is a table called users, and every user has an email address. The table is connected to a Users model. In the model class, email is defined as a public string, as you can see above. Would I have to run a query to return all email addresses?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154695/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-kamil1995b).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this as SelectListItem:

```
IList<SelectListItem> lst = new List<SelectListItem>();
        lst.Add(new SelectListItem()
            {
               Value = "Hello",
                Text = "World"
            });        
ViewBag.DropDownList = lst;
```

Or:

```
var u = new User();
ViewBag.DropDownList = u.EmailList //You need to populate your EmailList first before you declare it here.
return View(u);
```

Another option is this:

```
IList<SelectListItem> lst = new List<SelectListItem>();
        lst.Add(new SelectListItem()
            {
               Value = "Email",
               Text = "Email"
            });            
ViewBag.DropDownList = new SelectList(p.EmailList, "Value", "Text");
```

and on your View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Email, (SelectList)ViewBag.DropDownList, "---Select a value---", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

Comment: The first solution just returns one record `World` whereas it should return a list of emails. Have I missed the part where I should be looking/querying for them? I thought the model is able to resolve it automatically.

Comment: Of course it's just my example, you need to populate that with your desired record. I just give you lead on how you it should work and prevent the error.

Answer (score 0):

ensure that you are passing your selectlist in both get and post methods

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).